# Can I change the welcome page depending on URL?

Tags: google-app-engine, jetty

I have a single GAE app, which serves two different variations of the application depending on the invoked URL. Is it possible to have a per-url welcome page, without having the request map to a servlet which would slow the page load too much.

So, by way of example...

- My app lives at myapp.appspot.com
- I have two domains mapped to this app, myapp1.com and myapp2.com
- If the user accesses myapp1.com, I want to serve myapp1-index.html, and
  if he accesses myapp2.com, I want to serve myapp2-index.html

Answer (score 0):

I never played with GAE on Java but I'm guessing you could do something based on the requested URL. I believe you can check the requested URL with the following inside your request:

```
httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()
```

Where `httpServletRequest` is the `HttpServletRequest` parameter from your `doGet()` method.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to achieve this by configuration alone. If I pass the request to a servlet and then redirect based in the URI, the response time to serve the home page jumps dramatically.

Comment: @pinoyyid  It's not redirecting it's just rendering a different thing based on the URL.. how do you render the page?

Comment: I was hoping to do a URL rewrite via web.xml in some way. My mistake for using the word 'redirect', 'render' is the correct verb.

Comment: Well then I'm pretty sure it's not possible while you can make these kind of decisions in `web.xml` based on the requested URL..